# Duplicating body tag angular

Tags: parallax.js

I am trying to fix problem (4hours) with weird duplicate body tag,
but i dont have any idea how to fix it. Is there anyone who had same problem in past?

```html
<html lang="cs" ng-app="app" class="desktop landskape ng-scope">
    <head>...</head>
    <body style="overflow:hidden;"></body>
    <body class="loaded">...</body>
</html>
```

**App specification**

- AngularJS (v1.3.15)
- jQuery (v2.1.3)
- device.js (0.1.61)

Comment: This issue solved. There's problem with http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/ plugin.

Comment: your comment is, in fact, an answer: you could post it as an answer and accept it, so your post will no longer appear as "unanswered"

Comment: If it's plugin related issue, remove angularjs and jquery tags. Either delete the question/modify it/answer your own question. Modifying it would be a better approach to help others who would be using the same plugin and face the same problem, adding appropriate tags.